# Get function from abi.decode

Tags: solidity

I want to get external function from another contract so could you explain me how to do that?

for exampele:
I want to get func1 from myContract :

`(myContract memory function(uint) returns(address) func1) = abi.decode(_data,(myContract.func1(uint));`

Is this line correct or not?If not could you edit that in correct way?
thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to decode data that has been encoded or are you trying to make calls to an external function?

Here is a sample contract I wrote that does both:

```
contract DecodingDataAndCallingExternalFunction {


    function encodeData(uint x, string memory name) public pure returns(bytes memory) {
        return abi.encode(x,name);
    }

    function decodeData(bytes memory data) public pure returns(uint, string memory) {
        return abi.decode(data,(uint,string));
    }

    function callExternal(address addr) public view returns(address) {
        return Kontract(addr).externalFunc();
    }

    function viewAddr() public view returns(address) {
        return address(this);
    }

}


contract Kontract {
    
    function externalFunc() public view returns(address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }


}
```

You can copy these contracts into [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) and play around with them to get a better understanding.

Firstly if you encode data, in our case a uint256 and a string, then you will need to explicitly list the types when you decode the data. Straight from the [solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.19/abi-spec.html#basic-design):

> Data is encoded according to its type, as described in this specification. The encoding is not self describing and thus requires a schema in order to decode.

If you call `encodeData()` and then copy and paste the returned bytes into `decodeData()` you should see your original input returned back to you in a human readable format.

Now to call an external contract function, you need the contract's abi, specifically the function signature/selector, and you also need the contract's address. With these two things, you can call any function from any contract.

To test this out, you can deploy the `Kontract` and then pass its address to `callExternal()`, this will call the contract and return you the address that called the external function. To ensure the value returned is correct, call `viewAddr()`.